# Creating a trigger with SELECT Function

Tags: sql, plsql

Good day everyone,

I'm having trouble making my trigger work. As far as the functionality of the body and how it behaves, it does exactly as I intended for it to behave. However, when I start to fire the trigger, it returns an error in which Triggers should not have a SELECT statement from inside the main body. I'm still fairly new to coding and how to materialize the idea in my head into code. Hopefully someone could point me in a right direction on how change the Trigger I would like to have as a final result. Please see below script.

Update: Expected result would be whenever a user UPDATE a row and INSERT a new record via the application or job being run in the background, `S1_HOVER_REPORT` column would be updated with the value from the SELECT script and use the data from the `S1_HOVER` case result.

(Edit: I have updated the details of the problem above, added the Table being used and Error return)

```
Table: SITE
Column Name       Type        
------------------------------
ID                VARCHAR2(14)
NAME              VARCHAR2(70)
TYPE_CODE         VARCHAR2(2)
PARENT            VARCHAR2(14)
S1_HOVER_REPORT   VARCHAR2(14)
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MESS.S1_HOVER_REPORT
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON MESS.SITE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE (SELECT S1.ID,
                  S1.NAME,
                  S1.TYPE_CODE,
                  S1.PARENT AS PARENT1,
                  S2.PARENT AS PARENT2,
                  S1.S1_HOVER_REPORT,
                  CASE
                     WHEN (S1.TYPE_CODE = 'H2') THEN S1.PARENT
                     WHEN (S1.TYPE_CODE = 'S1') THEN S2.PARENT
                     ELSE S1.ID
                  END AS S1_HOVER
             FROM SITE S1,
                     (SELECT ID,
                             NAME,
                             PARENT,
                             TYPE_CODE
                        FROM site
                       WHERE type_code='H2') S2
            WHERE S1.PARENT=S2.ID
               OR S1.ID = S2.PARENT) S3
   SET S3.S1_HOVER_REPORT = S3.S1_HOVER;
END;
```

```
Error returned when Trigger fired:
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
ORA-06512: at "MES.S1_HOVER_REPORT", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MES.S1_HOVER_REPORT'
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

(**Update:** I have included the updated trigger and it's now compiling without any issue, but I'm having errors whenever I try updating a record)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MESS.S1_HOVER_REPORT
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MESS.SITE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   v_S1_HOVER_REPORT VARCHAR2(14);
BEGIN
SELECT CASE
           WHEN (S1.TYPE_CODE = 'H2') THEN S1.PARENT
           WHEN (S1.TYPE_CODE = 'S1') THEN S2.PARENT
           ELSE (S1.ID)
        END AS S1_HOVER
   INTO v_S1_HOVER_REPORT
   FROM SITE S1,
       (SELECT ID,
               NAME,
               PARENT,
               TYPE_CODE
          FROM site
         WHERE type_code='H2') S2
  WHERE S1.PARENT=S2.ID
     OR S1.ID = S2.PARENT;

:NEW.S1_HOVER_REPORT := v_S1_HOVER_REPORT;
END;
```

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table MES.SITE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "MES.S1_HOVER_REPORT", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MES.S1_HOVER_REPORT'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a trigger to me.  The first things I look for are `:new` and `:old`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so then the :new and :old is a mandatory function in creating the trigger? I can't really wrap my head around on how to use this functionality to achieve that type of UPDATE in the body.

Comment: 1.Provide the structure of the table on which the trigger is based on. 2. Usage of :new and :old is not mandatory but why do you need then each row trigger and with no reference to the current row being updated. 3. Also you have to explain your use case fairly instead only mentioning about not working part. Finally not to mention of course we can have select inside a trigger

Comment: @EiroSpades . . . They are not mandatory.  It is just hard to imagine a useful trigger that doesn't use them.  I mean, there are some -- counts of inserts or printing a message, but they are pretty simple.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 - I have updated the description above. I apologize that I wasn't that specific.


@GordonLinoff - I did saw only a handful of triggers in our database that use the ```:new and :old``` but couldn't really figure out how to incorporate it in the result I'm targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly from the error message

```
An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which map to a non-key-preserved table.
```

S3 is the veiw ( you are creating the view by doing a select inside an update statment).  You can try and change this to have key preservation but I really wouldn't know how.

The error suggests updating the base tables not the view. So as mentioned in the comments :old and :new are your friend.

:OLD holds all the values of the table the trigger is created on BEFORE the update (null if insert)

:NEW holds all the values of the table the trigger is created on AFTER the update / insert.....

So if I understand what you want to do correctly you would need to...

1. declare a variable eg v_S1_hover_report
2. do your select returning whatever value you need into this variable
3. set the value in your site table by doing

   :NEW.S1_HOVER_REPORT := v_S1_hover_report

By setting this value into the :NEW object when a commit happens it will be committed to the database. This completely removes the need for an update statement in the trigger.

You can also use :NEW.id in your select statement to filter it down to the record you are updating if it is helpfull

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MESS.S1_HOVER_REPORT
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON MESS.SITE
FOR EACH ROW

v_test varchar2(10);

BEGIN

select 'Your value' into v_test from dual;

:new.s1_hover_report := v_test;

END;
```

**OR**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MESS.S1_HOVER_REPORT
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON MESS.SITE
FOR EACH ROW

v_test varchar2(10);

BEGIN

select 'Your value' into :new.s1_hover_report from dual;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I'll try what you suggested in my end and hopefully that could solve my problem. I'll give an update once I have tested this out. Again, thank you!

Comment: Sorry to ask this but I can't seem to figure out how to set the value in my ```SITE``` table without using ```UPDATE```. Is there some trick to doing this and incorporating it into my ```SELECT``` script inside the trigger.

Comment: Hi @EiroSpades I have added two code samples, with a simplified version of your select. The first splits it into two steps so it is very obvious what it is doing.  The second combines these two steps to a single step for concise code.

Comment: Hi @ShaunPeterson - thank you for providing me some simple sample and it worked for me. However, when trying to fire the trigger like ```UPDATE``` script, it returns a different error. That was the initial error that I was facing regarding the use of ```SELECT``` script in my trigger. Again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi @EiroSpades, no problem glad I was able to help.  If it has resolved your issue please click on the Green tick to accept the answer.